# Hint to an Inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have the following problem in my book-

> Prove that for all non-negative real numbers $x, y, z$- $$ 6(x+y-z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)+27xyz \le 10(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3\over 2} $$

And the **solution**:
$$\color{red}{10(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3\over 2}-6(x+y-z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(10\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-6(x+y-z))$$ $$ =(x^2+y^2+z^2)\left(\color{red}{{10\over 3}\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(2^2+2^2+1^2)}}-6(x+y-z)\right) $$ By C-S,
$$ \ge(x^2+y^2+z^2)\left({10(2x+2y+z)\over 3}-6(x+y-z)\right)={(x^2+y^2+z^2)(2x+2y+28z)\over 3}$$By AM-GM,
$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 9\sqrt[9]{x^8y^8z^2\over 4^8} $ and $ 2x+2y+28z\ge 9\sqrt[9]{4^8xyz^7} $
and multiplication accompanied by division with 3 ends the proof.

The validity of the proof is undoubted, but I want to know that how the author comes up with such an *idea*?
What has the question reflected that hints the major steps to the proof in red?
**Note**:- I want just the *idea* that leads to the proof, not a solution.

Comment: Honestly, factoring problems are really just a matter of pattern recognition. I doubt you are going to get a insightful answer here.

Comment: Yes, but I need these phrases like "pattern recognition" that are the ideas leading the proof. This is what is important for me, not the proof. I do not want to get something universal, just related to the inequalities used in the proof.

Comment: I think C-S played a greater role at the third step in red, than the AM-GM at the end.

Comment: As I mentioned in your other post, "the equality case gives us a hint about what inequalities to use, and how." With equality at $(2, 2, 1)$, that tells us that the naive AM-GM or CS wouldn't work because the equality condition of "all terms equal" isn't satisfied. We needed $ \frac{x}{2} = \frac{y}{2} = \frac{z}{1}$, which explains how to create the first attempt at CS (if one was inclined to use CS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the equality occurs for $(x,y,z)=(2,2,1)$ and we want to delete a radical.

We can try to make it by using C-S:
$$\sqrt{(2^2+2^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq2x+2y+z$$  and it gives a right inequality.

The rest is smooth enough.

Comment: And how did the author had in mind to transfer $6(x+y-z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ to the greater side of the inequality? And in the book, it gives that the equality holds for $x=y=2z$ up to permutation.

Comment: @Book Of Flames The author wants that the equality after using C-S would be true. For which he chose the expression, which you saw. I can create for you an inequality, that for the proof you need to understand before, when the equality occurs. After this understanding the rest is smooth enough. Do you want?

Comment: Yes, I get very less problems such as these.

Comment: @Book Of Flames This is what I baked for you: Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positives such that $xy+xz+yz=1$. Prove that: $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{8}{y}+\frac{13}{z}\geq30$. The proof should be by using  AM-GM only. Without using AM-GM even I can prove it! :) Good luck!

Comment: Equality holds for $x={1\over 5}$, $y={2\over 3}$ and $z=1$.

Comment: @Book Of Flames Yes! Now, you can find a proof.

Comment: Actually I found the solution half an hour after your question was posted, but am still working to get a way through the proof. Getting the coefficients on the LHS as the solution to the equality case didn't help. Now noticing $30=2\times 3\times 5$, but don't know how to proceed. Any hints for the first step?

Comment: @Book Of Flames Let $x=\frac{a}{5}$...

Comment: The resting inequality is very appealing- ${5\over a}+{12\over b}+{13\over c}\geq5+12+13$ with the constrait- $xy+yz+zx=1$.

Comment: But this is the resultant of your substitution.

Comment: Yes, yes. It depend on how you want to use it.

Comment: Applying the same substitution to the constraint makes it very ugly and tough to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111104/discussion-between-michael-rozenberg-and-book-of-flames).

Comment: The **Solution**: Your substitution leads to ${5\over a}+{12\over b}+{13\over c}\geq 30$ when $2ab+10bc+3ca=15$. By a clever application of AM-GM, the inequality turns to ${2\over \sqrt{ab}}+{10\over \sqrt{bc}}+{3\over \sqrt{ca}}\geq 15$ which is true by Holder, $(2ab+10bc+3ca)\left({2\over \sqrt{ab}}+{10\over \sqrt{bc}}+{3\over \sqrt{ca}}\right)^2\geq 15^{3}$ which is true.